# MySQL statement does not work in WordPress PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select, set

This select statement works perfectly in MySQL but when I try to use it in my WordPress PHP, it does not work.

From what I found online, think one can only pass one statement to `$wpdb->get_results()`, so one needs to replace the SET variables with the actual values. It should be OK to assign to variables within the SELECT statement, one just can't SET them ahead of time.

Thing is, I don't know how to change this so it works. Can anyone help me?

```
SET @maxp:=10; SET @point:=@maxp; SET @prev:='';

SELECT
    medlemsnr,
    navn,
    SUM(point) AS score 
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF (art!=@prev, @point:=@maxp, @point:=@point-1) AS point,
        @prev:=art,
        navn,
        medlemsnr,
        art,
        maxvaegt 
    FROM (
        SELECT medlemsnr,navn,art,MAX(vægt) AS maxvaegt 
        FROM ct_storfanger_indberetninger
        WHERE YEAR(dato)=2017
        GROUP BY medlemsnr, navn, art
        ORDER BY art, maxvaegt DESC
    ) l
) s 
WHERE point>0 
GROUP BY medlemsnr, navn  
ORDER BY score DESC
```

I have tried this in my PHP but it fails.

```
$samletstilling = $wpdb->get_results("The above statement");
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay....so I found a solution

```
$wpdb->get_results("SET @maxp:=10;");
$wpdb->get_results("SET @point:=@maxp;");
$wpdb->get_results("SET @prev:='';");
$samletstilling = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT
    medlemsnr, navn, SUM(point) AS score 
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF (art!=@prev, @point:=@maxp, @point:=@point-1) AS point,
        @prev:=art,
        navn,
        medlemsnr,
        art,
        maxvaegt 
    FROM (
        SELECT
            medlemsnr,
            navn,
            art,
            MAX(vægt) AS maxvaegt
        FROM ct_storfanger_indberetninger
        WHERE YEAR(dato)=2017
        GROUP BY medlemsnr,art
        ORDER BY art,maxvaegt DESC) l
    ) s 
    WHERE point>0 GROUP BY medlemsnr ORDER BY score DESC"
);
```